# Simple Java Issue

Tags: java

This isn't working the way I expect it to. Sample input will include an asterisk that will resemble ether 0 or 1. The rest is comparing to see if the numbers match up. When I  try to see if a character an asterisk it doesn't work the way I expect it to.

Samples:

org = *01

bit = 001 || 101 || 011

```
public static void doesItWork(String org, String bit)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= org.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(org.substring(i, i + 1));
            if(org.substring(i, i + 1) != "*" && org.substring(i, i + 1) !=  bit.substring(i, i + 1))
                break;

            if(i == org.length() - 1)
                System.out.println(bit);
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!=` on `String`s doesn't do what you want it to do.  [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) explains, but in brief,

> ```
> org.substring(i, i + 1) != "*"
> ```

should probably be

```
!org.substring(i, i + 1).equals("*")
```

or ideally

```
org.charAt(i) != '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

!= with Strings might not be good idea. Try !x.equals("*");

Comment: Also if you are a newcomer to java from a different language but know regular expressions, try them out in java, java.util.Regex